# Reading +IPD response from serial.read() using Arduino UNO and ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, esp8266, communication, softwareserial

I have a python server running on my PC and I am using an Arduino Uno (wifi enabled by a ESP8266 chip) as the client.
I can make the the server and client communicate using *AT commands* as shown below:

```
SoftwareSerial esp (8,9);

   void setup()
   {
   esp.begin(9600);
   esp.println("AT+CWMODE=3");
   delay(100);
   esp.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"192.168.8.100\",5555");
   delay(1000);
   esp.println("AT+CIPSEND=3");
   delay(100);
   esp.println("bbb");
   delay(100); }
```

The string *"bbb"* is recieved on the server and the server responds back, which is shown in the serial monitor as:

```
+IPD,19:the string is found
```

I want to read this response and use it back in the code for further conditional statements. But i am unable to do this. So far i have tried these methods.

1st method by using *esp.readString()* as shown below:

```
String buffer="";
while (esp.available()>0) 
    buffer+= esp.readString();   
Serial.print(i4);
```

2nd by using *esp.read()* as shown below:

```
String buffer="";
char c;
while (esp.available()>0) {
    c= esp.read();
    buffer+=c;}
Serial.print(buffer);    // i have also tried using esp.write() directly for prinitng here intead of storing it in a buffer
```

These two methods returned with incomplete information in the response string *buffer* ie i only get:

```
busy s...

Recv 3 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,19:the string
```

I can not get the entire response in the *buffer* as mentioned in the start. On the other hand if i execute the command `AT+CWLAP` and store its response in the *buffer* string, i get the entire thing. So i cant understand why is there a difference between the two.
Lastly i have also used *esp.readBytes()* as shown:

```
char c[500];
esp.readBytes(c,400);
esp.write(c);
```

This code gives me the whole response sometimes but sometimes it just gives a long garbage value. But the times it does give me the complete `+IPD` response, it switches some of the alphabets ie `the string is found` becomes `the strjng is gound`

If anyone could help me out i'll be very thankful.

Comment: A `while(Serial.available()>0)` does not guarantee, that all bytes have been received. Sometimes there is a small delay between bytes, which you cannot control. The Arduino will exit the `while` loop, but short after that, more bytes are received, without the program ḱnowing. Somehow your Arduino has to know, when the message is complete (through a delimiter character or maybe a timeout).

Comment: @chrisl i have also tried this using a _for loop_ like so:

`esp.println("bbb");
 delay(100);
 char c[100];
 for(int i=0;i<80;i++){
    c[i]= esp.read();
    delay(10);
    Serial.write(c[i]);
   }`

Which gives me the following output:
`busy s...

Recv 3 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,19:the string⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮`

I assumed after this that the buffer must be empty thats why the reverse question marks appeared. I still have no clue on what to do next

Comment: The reverse question marks depict a character, that has no meaning in ASCII, e.g. a value greater than 127. The `read()` function returns `-1`,  when the buffer is empty, which translates to an unsigned value of `255`. So you are right, that the buffer is empty there. That is strange. How many bytes do you receive correctly with this method?

Comment: @chrisl When i run the command `AT+CWLAP` i can get upto 400B in the _buffer_ variable. But in the commands that receive a response from the server i.e. i use `AT+CIPSEND` and my sever sends a response which includes `+IPD` i can only get max 64B. I have shown this in the original question. I dont understand why this is happening because i have used the same reading technique for both commands